# CKEditor5 integration with vue.js and laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, ckeditor

I am trying to upload ckeditor to my project, but for 7 hours I try and it does not go away. I searched google, installed from 30 packages (npm), I did with tutorials and slowly give up. Please help, I need to configure wysiwyg editor globally for all views that contain id = "description".

I have something like that: 
component CKeditor.vue

```
<template>

</template>

<script>
    import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic'
    import VueCkeditor from 'vue-ckeditor5'

    export default {
        components: {
            'vue-ckeditor': VueCkeditor.component
        },
        data(){
            return {
                value1: 'hello',
                value2: 'world',
                editors: {
                    classic: ClassicEditor
                }
            }
        },
        template: 
        `<vue-ckeditor type="classic" v-model="value1" :editors="editors"></vue-ckeditor>`
    }
</script>
```

View create.blade.php:

```
<ckeditor type="classic" v-model="value1" class="form-control" rows="5" name="description" id="description" placeholder="Description" maxlength="3000"></ckeditor>
```

app.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import axios from 'axios'

Vue.prototype.$http = axios

require('./bootstrap');

Vue.component('ckeditor', require('./components/CKeditor.vue').default);

window.Vue = require('vue');
window.onload = function () {
    const app = new Vue({
        el: '#app'
    });
}
```

the works were on the tutorial from https://github.com/igorxut/vue-ckeditor5

please help me run this wysiwyg editor. So much thanks... :*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll give you  from the begining to the end how you can  run ckeditor 5 with laravel and vuejs just follow this steps

-1 install CKEditor in laravel with npm

```
npm install --save @ckeditor/ckeditor5-vue @ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic
```

-2 add this code in app.js file

```
import CKEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-vue';

Vue.use( CKEditor );
```

-3 create a component for ckeditor  in app.js

```
Vue.component('ck-editor', require('./components/ckeditor.vue').default);
```

-4 add this code to your ckeditor.vue file

```
<template>
    <div>
        <ckeditor :editor="editor" v-model="editorData" :config="editorConfig"></ckeditor>
        <button v-on:click="emptyEditor()">Empty the editor</button>
        <br><br>
         <h2>Editor display html code </h2>
         <br>
         <div>{{editorData}}</div>
         <h2>Editor display html Result </h2> 
         <br>
         <button v-on:click="displayEditorResult()">display result </button>
         <br><br>
         
        <div id="resultingText"></div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';

    export default {
        
        data() {
            return {
                
                editor: ClassicEditor,
                editorData: 'ckeditor 5 for laravel and vuejs',
                editorConfig: {
                    // The configuration of the editor.
                },
             

            };
        },
       
           mounted(){
                    
                    console.log('Component mounted.')
                },
                methods: {
            emptyEditor() {
                this.editorData = '';
            },
            displayEditorResult(){
                document.getElementById('resultingText').innerHTML = this.editorData;
            }
        }

    }
</script>
```

-5 create a blade file  and add this code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>ckeditor 5  wyswyg</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/app.css">

</head>
<body>
<div id="app">
    <ck-editor></ck-editor>
    
</div>

<script src="/js/app.js"></script>
<script>

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

finally run the code and it will display CKEditor 5

hope my answer can help you